# Minor CSS issue

Tags: css

I am new to the designing/programming world so I am sure the issue is easy to solve. I am trying to add the moz-box-shadow effect to my header. But as soon as I add that component, the header which is taking up space horizontally shortens up. I want the header to be like Twitter's, where they use a shadow effect.

```
#header {
    background-color: #990000;
    width:101.3%;
    margin-left:-8px;
    margin-top:-8px;
    height:40px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #D7D7D7;
}
```

Also, the way I have set the width is it likely going to create cross browser issues?

Comment: Could you upload a little screen snippet that clearly shows the effect you are trying to achieve? Pardon my ignorance, but I don't use Twitter, and its difficult to find an example of this. Thanks

Comment: You might be better of posting this at stackoverflow. That said, the box-shadow attribute should have no affect on layout at all. So, there's likely something else going on. We really need to see your entire page (ie, a link)

Comment: This is not a Graphic Design question. And you probably will have some browsers issues. Especially since you're using a mozilla specific attribute. And it should have no effect on your code.

Comment: @Johannes, agreed, not graphic design. but there is also a discussion on meta about increasing this sites scope: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-we-increase-this-ses-scope.

Comment: @Johannes and @Jailps: When I initially read the question, it hadn't occurred to me that it would be considered off-topic to current guidelines simply because there has been so much chatter in meta about opening up the scope of the site to boost its health. I think we should let this one float out there for a little while and see what happens.

Comment: @Philip Regan: I've been reading those metas as well. But this does seem to be directly related to code. And while I agree that the scope of this site _should_ increase, to take topics directly covered on other SEs would just make finding answers, overall, more difficult, don't you think?

Comment: Design ≠ development.

Comment: If the stack* network is going to fragment into all these micro-subjects, then we need to be disciplined in what gets posted where. Otherwise you end up with issues like this...is a CSS design question Graphic design? Web developer? Stack Overflow? If we allow overlap, that could be OK, but likely see lots of cross posting. ALL THAT SAID...I disagree with MikeNGarret...there is no clear line dividing design and developent.

Comment: I agree with @DA01 here. In this case, at least with web design, development == design because the code in question creates a design-related decision and/or issue. How is this change in CSS to affect a shadow any different than a how-to question related to using the drop shadow tool in Photoshop? In both cases, a design issue is being weighed: the drop shadow. If the scope of GD.SE is opened up to allow UI questions as has been proposed, then these types of code-inclusive questions *will* become more prevalent.

Comment: That is to assume that the drop-shadow is the true issue here. It could be an issue with the poster's actual (non-design) code. It's difficult to draw a line. But I do insist this is best for StackOverflow. ... Also if the reasoning is that "well this code the design of the website" then I would argue, that ALL code is design. Coding is an art in itself, I think it's unwise to merge the two.

Comment: My gripe with the fragmentation everywhere is that, at least with web design, it's a highly collaborative process. You need User Experience working with Graphic design working with HTML/CSS developers working with the DBA working with the Copywriter working with the Ruby team working with...

As such, I suppose there will always be overlap with this model.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that we move the discussion on whether or not this is on topic to the meta site. I've already opened a question, see http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99/css-html-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known bug with box-shadow in some browsers which has been documented but not resolved yet.

For cross compatible CSS code (not sure it'll validate with the vendor prefixes) use this:

```
.shadow {
        -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
        /* For IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
        /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
    }
```

You could forgo all this and just use a BG image, 25px wide and whatever you want tall, with the drop shadow as you want. Save it as a 24bit PNG and it will render as pretty as you see in Photoshop.

As an aside, questions about CSS/HTML should go on Stackoverflow.com and not here, this is a site for Graphic Design. Questions about website design should go on Doctype.com.

Hope some of this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The `width:101.3%` will probably not cause cross browser issues, but it will cause your page to always show vertical scrollbar.

What *will* cause cross browser issues is the `-moz-box-shadow` effect, which is Firefox specific. See [Kyle Sevenoaks' answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/841/minor-css-issue/865#865) for how to support all browsers with the shadow effect.